# Receiver class does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean getDevelopmentMode()'

Tags: kotlin, testing, gradle, ktor, localserver

I'm trying to run local server with KTOR and to cover it with tests. I wrote some code and after writing some tests, the tests successfully raised the local server and passed. However, if I try to start a local server, I get this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver
> class io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading does
> not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method
> 'abstract boolean getDevelopmentMode()' of interface
> io.ktor.application.ApplicationEnvironment.

I attach the code and the stack trace from below

#### server.kt

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.features.*
import io.ktor.gson.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable


fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson()
    }

    routing {
        val controller = Controller()

        get("/converter{from}{to}") {
            try {
                val fromCurrency = call.request.queryParameters["from"]
                val toCurrency = call.request.queryParameters["to"]
                val rate = controller.converter(fromCurrency, toCurrency)
                val response = Response(
                    "1 $fromCurrency = $rate $toCurrency",
                    null
                )
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, response)
            } catch (e: ControllerException) {
                val response = Response(
                    null,
                    e.message
                )
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response)
            }
        }

        get {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Response())
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
data class Response(
    @SerialName("converterResponse")
    val converterResponse: String? = null,
    @SerialName("errorMessage")
    val errorMessage: String? = null
)
```

#### converterTest.kt

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class ConverterTest {
    @Test
    fun `Identical Correct Currencies`() {
        withTestApplication(Application::module) {
            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/converter?from=USD&to=USD").apply {
                assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
                val expectedResponse = Response("1 USD = 1 USD")
                assertEquals(
                    Gson().toJson(expectedResponse),
                    response.content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean getDevelopmentMode()' of interface io.ktor.application.ApplicationEnvironment.
at io.ktor.application.Application.<init>(Application.kt:20)
at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:269)
at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:125)
at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:245)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:126)
at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:26)
at ServerKt.main(server.kt:11)
```

#### build.gradle

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.30" // or kotlin("multiplatform") or any other kotlin plugin
    application
}

group = "me.admin"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx") }
    maven { url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor") }
}

dependencies {
    val kotlin_version = "1.5.30"
    val ktor_version = "1.6.3"

    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:1.4.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.4.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:1.4.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:1.3.2-1.4-M2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.7.2")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha5")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.0-RC")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-test-host:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-gson:$ktor_version")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClassName = "ServerKt"
}
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your build Gradle file?

Comment: Yep, sure! ^^ 
Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency `io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:1.4.0` causes the `AbstractMethodError`. To fix it just use the same version for all Ktor dependencies:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
```